# Error couting an Integer

Tags: c++, integer, initialization

recently I took it upon myself to start working on the Project Euler challenges. I am on problem seven, and have encountered a strange error in my code. In my code, I have a variable called, `count` that counts the number of prime numbers found, but when I try to print it, it prints out as null.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  bool isPrime = true;

  for(int i = 1; i <= 10000000000;)
  {
      int count;
      for(int factor = 1; factor = i; factor++)
      {

          if(i%factor == 0)
          {
              isPrime = false;
              break;
          }
      }

      if(isPrime) {count = count + 1;}

      std::cout << count + "-";
      if(count == 10001)
      {
          std::cout << count;
          std::cout << i + "Final \n";
          break;
      }
      i++;
  }


}
```

When the line `std::cout << count + "-";` runs, the output is:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

etc. I think it has something to do with the initialization of `counts`, but I'm not sure. Thanks for any help!

Comment: You either need a better compiler / need to turn up your warning setting / or actually pay attention to the warnings.  Your code throws 5 different warnings for incorrect code: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6ef7a57438ba8b8c

Comment: "_Initialized Variable couts as Nothing_" But.. The variable `count` is **not** initialized.. Do you know what initialization is?

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks for letting me know, this is my first time using g++, as I just installed it 4.5 hours ago. Good to know.

Comment: A good starting place for g++'s warnings is to add -Wall -Wextra to the command line. I also add -pedantic.  If you want to make it so that you cannot ignore the warnings, a good choice while learning, add -Werror to turn warnings into errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
std::cout << count << "-";
```

By using the "+" operator you're concatenating a string with nothing, thus outputting just the "-" string.

Alternatively you can do

```
std::cout << std::to_string(count) + "-";
```

Comment: Oh, that's interesting. I have done a lot of Java, but not much C++. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I wouldn't suggest your alternative suggestions.  It doesn't gain you anything and is expensive.

Comment: @JamesKirk Why would you assume the semantics of Java, and C++ would be the same? I suggest reading a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the errors mentioned above, in the line of code

```
for(int factor = 1; factor = i; factor++)
```

You are assigning factor to have a value of I rather than checking an equality like this:

```
factor == i;
```

I assume this is what you are trying to do.

Comment: This should be a comment (-1), but you can't comment yet and this is really useful information for the asker (+1). Comes out even.

Comment: Now that I can comment, let me defend myself by saying that it would have been a comment if I had access to do so at the time.